# RAM rapidily increases while running this Java program

Tags: java, garbage-collection, ram

The program is receiving the image data in bytes from IP camera and then process the image. The first time when the program starts uses 470Mb of RAM, and in every 1 second it increases up to 15Mb, it will continue till there is no enough space and the computer hanged up.

*The method `getImage()` is called every 100ms*

I have done some experiment going to share here. The original code is like this: (in which the buffer is created only once and after that, it can be reused)

```
private static final int WIDTH = 640;
private static final int HEIGHT = 480;
private byte[] sJpegPicBuffer = new byte[WIDTH * HEIGHT]; 

private Mat readImage() throws Exception {
    boolean isGetSuccess = camera.getImage(lUserID, sJpegPicBuffer, WIDTH * HEIGHT);
    if (isGetSuccess) {
        return Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(sJpegPicBuffer), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the above code, RAM goes up to Computer hang up (99% 10Gb). Then I changed the code like this: (in every loop it will create a new buffer)

```
private static final int WIDTH = 640;
private static final int HEIGHT = 480; 

private Mat readImage() throws Exception {
    byte[] sJpegPicBuffer = new byte[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    boolean isGetSuccess = camera.getImage(lUserID, sJpegPicBuffer, WIDTH * HEIGHT);
    if (isGetSuccess) {
        return Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(sJpegPicBuffer), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this above code the RAM goes up to about 43% (5Gb)and then freed up.

Now the question is in the first block of code seems to be optimized, the buffer can be reused avoiding to create new space of memory in every call, but the result is not something we want. **Why?**

In the second block of code, it seems that the code is not as optimized as the first one, but works well than the first one.

But in general why the RAM increasing up to 10Gb in the first case and 5Gb in the second case. How can we control this situation?

Comment: did you update your JVM to latest version?

Comment: There is nothing in this code that would indicate how or why the ram usage goes up. What library are you using? Did you try using a profiler?

Comment: @NitishKumarDiwakar It is already the latest version java version "1.8.0_131"

Comment: @matt Yes I am using IP camera SDK, that had .dll and Java interface to their C/C++ code.

Comment: The `byte[]` doesn't take up much room at all. Why do you think this method is the source of your leak? What do you do with the `Mat`, are you keeping a reference?

Comment: @matt Because when I create the Mat object via USB Camera or video file, everything goes well, and also I don't keep the reference. But when I get the Image from the IP camera the situation changed, even when I change the code also, effects the situation.

Comment: The memory usage pattern of your second implementation is to be expected: Java will allocate memory until usage comes close to the limit, then the garbage collector kicks in and frees resources that are no longer used.

Comment: What is your `camera` then? Does it have some method to release resources? Did you try visualVM to see which objects are consuming so much memory?

Comment: You can set the max memory, `-Xmx` and it will attempt to keep a smaller memory footprint, and OutOfMemoryError if you exceed that.

Comment: @matt The camera is an IP camera which they provide an SDK, through their SDK we can connect and receive the data, there are 4 steps: init, login, get the stream, and log out. nothing else to release the source. OK I will try to use visualVM or profiler to check.

Comment: I meant, the object/class the camera is. Not the physical camera. Is the API available online so we can look at it? Possibly you found a bug, and possibly you are missing something from the API that can help.

Comment: @matt No the API is not available online, as I contact with their technical support engineers, they send me the exact code to get the image from the camera, but the problem still exists, so the PC does not have enough memory for this task (10Gb). I have done every step according to their suggestions.

Comment: Did you set `-Xmx` to be something small so you get an OOM error instead of just using all of your memory?

Comment: Also, one difference that could be happening. If your accumulating references to the enclosing class, then the first technique would cause you to accumulate more memory. For example here, if you started accumulating A's they would take up more memory than accumulating B's.

Comment: @matt It is why I came to ask the question here, that two blocks of code are using different memory space, so I wonder it is why? Basically, the first one must work more better than the second, but it is not.

Comment: My example points out a way your first one could be using more memory than your second one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a speculation, though I've seen similar scenario in real live few times.

Your Java code is interacting with native camera SDK (dll). Native code is like to allocating buffers in non JVM memory and use some internal Java objects to access that buffers. Common (a very poor) practice is to relay on Java object finalizer deallocate native buffer if it is not used any more.

Finalizers rely on garbage collector to trigger them, and this is a reason that pattern often fails. Although, finalizer is guarantied to run eventually, in practice it would not happen as long as there are enough space in Java heap and native memory would not be deallocated in timely fashion.

Java heap size have hard limit, but native memory pool used by C/C++ can grow as long as OS allow it to grow.

**Concerning your problem**

I assume in your first snippet, Java heap traffic is low. GC is idle and no finalizers are executes, thus memory allocated outside of Java heap keeps growing.

In second snippet, your are creating pressure on Java heap forcing GC to run frequently. As a side effect of GC finializer are executed and native memory released.

Instead of finalizers and buffer allocated in native code, your camera SDK may relay on Java direct memory buffers (these memory is direct accessing for C code so it is convenient to pass data over JVM boundary). Though effect would be mostly the same, because Java direct buffers implementation is using same pattern (with phantom references in stead of finalizers).

**Suggestions**

- [`-XX:+PrintGCDetails`](http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/10/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) and [`-XX:+PrintReferenceGC`](http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/10/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) options would print information about reference processing so you can verify if finalizer/phantom references are indeed being used.
- look at you camera's SDK docs to see is it is possible to release native resources early via API
- option [`-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=X`](http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/10/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) can be used to cap direct buffer usage, if your camara's SDK relays on them. Though it is not a solution, but a safety net to let your application OOM before OS memory is exhausted
- force every few frames (e.g. `System.gc()`). This is another poor option as behavior of `System.gc()` is JVM dependent.

PS 
[This is my post](http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/03/finalizers-and-references-in-java.html) about resource management with finalizers and phantom references.

Comment: Hmm, It seems that you figured out the main reason, that it can the problem with the SDK. But here when I pass the array of bytes and also it has passed by reference and not but value, so in the C/C++ code in the SDK can get this reference address and put the data, because of this reason I declared the buffer as global (first block of code). But it was not the thing which I think that can be. I don't know how the bytes array can be passed to the underline C/C++ code? I think there will be a lot of copying process will be done during getting the data of image?

Comment: On heap Java object cannot be passed to C/C++ code (with few very special exceptions). C/C++ code can access array via API which is fairly inefficient. Java can create special "direct" ByteBuffer objects which is accessible from Java and can be deferenced to C/C++ memory pointer.